# Windows 8.1 bizarre audio issues

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, windows-registry, asus-laptop

I have an Asus K52JT laptop running Windows 8.1 since three months ago. Audio speakers have worked fine since this week. At startup it is working, but after a while (15-60 minutes) it **eventually stops** playing sound while the programs show that they still play. However the headphones always work well.

What I have I tried:

- Reinstalled the drivers of the high definition audio device
- Installed codec pack for Windows 8.1
- After this was not working I restored the system to one week before.
- Tried bat file to restart Windows audio

Comment: What audio chipset are you using? Can you tell me the driver name?

Comment: It appears ok in the device manager.
Driver name: High Definition Audio Device.
Hardware Id: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_14F1&DEV_5069&SUBSYS_104313F3&REV_1003.